# Error in hclustfun(distr) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10) message using heatmap.2 function

Tags: r, heatmap

I am trying to make a heatmap using the heatmap.2 function in rstudio.

```
m <- data.matrix(heat_try)
> heatmap.2 (m, main = "Title", trace= "none", margins = c (3,12), Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE, scale = c("row"))
> bio <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))
> heatmap.2 (m, col= bio, main = "Title", trace= "none", margins = c (3,12), Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE, scale = c("row"))
```

I get the message "Error in hclustfun(distr) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)"

I tried changing the NA cells to 0 (zeros), and the function worked. However, I would like my NAs (or zeros) to be shown in black in the heatmap.

How can I do that? I cannot use the datasheet with NAs and the function na.color="black", because I get the error message "Error in hclustfun(distr) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)". Thanks in advance!

The sample data is below.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfgJF.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data that gives the error?

Comment: Hi Joe, I provided a sample of the data in the original post. I get the Warning message: In data.matrix(heat_try) : NAs introduced by coercion. I try to plot the heatmap using the code    heatmap.2 (heat_try, main = "Title", trace= "none", margins = c (3,12), Rowv=TRUE, Colv=TRUE, scale = c("row"))  , but I get  the error message "Error in hclustfun(distr) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)"     How can I fix that and make the empty cells (NAs) be represented in black in the heatmap? Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is with your input data. It should be a numeric matrix and you can check this with `class(m)`. For example, maybe one of your columns has a strange symbol which is causing it to be converted to a character class. If so, you'll have to find this and remove it.